# Crystal Reports sub reports in same group

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report per client and within this report I have several sub reports, each within their own group.  The SRs are referencing views I have created in the connected MS SQL database which show the particular client records.

I'd like to show two SR's on the same group level, but which reference different views in MS SQL.  The issue I've come across is that where SR1 has data relating to the client but SR2 does not, no information is being shown in either SR1 or SR2 within the grouped layer.

Ideally I'd like to keep the SR's separate, although I guess I could create a new view in MS SQL just tying these two sets of data together.

Is there something I'm missing in Crystal Reports which basically says 'Show all data from SR1 results, even if SR2 results are null'.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: have you tried linking?

Comment: Hi Siva, Yes, don't know why I didn't think that far ahead!  The two previously separate SR's are now their own linked view in CR.  This has everything working fine as I would have hoped.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, thank you Siva.  Gonna keep bashing on till the next!